# How to build pjsip as DLL in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, pjsip

I follow the instructions here
http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__pj__dll__target.htm

But I got errors, after some research in net I found below answer. But this also produces more errors.

**Ansewer from Internet:**http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.pjsip/16764

```
I managed to build pjsua.dll some time ago and wrote down a simple 
how-to. Maybe you will be lucky with that. It is in doxygen:

 <at> subsubsection subsubsec-pjsip-1x Building PJSIP version 1.x
-# Download sources from http://www.pjsip.org/.
-# Open solution in Visual Studio.
    If you use VS2010 (and maybe newer), do not open the  <at> c .sln file, but
     <at> c .dsw file for older Visual C++ since it does not contain mobile targets
    preventing from import.
-# Create empty file  <at> c pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    or copy it from  <at> c config_site_sample.h and add following code:
 <at> code
#define PJ_DLL  1
#ifdef _LIB
#   define PJ_EXPORTING 1
#endif
 <at> endcode
    This will build PJProject using shared libraries.
-# Choose configuration according to your needs: statically or dynamically
    linked release or debug LIBC. Recommended: <b>Release-Dynamic</b>. Do 
not forget
    to set Win32 platform.
-# At project  <at> c pjsua_lib, set Configuration type to DLL and check 
dependencies
    to the same values as in  <at> c libpjproject.
    Add  <at> c ws2_32.lib into linker input libraries. Put  <at> c 
_pjmedia_tonegen_create2
    into Linker > Input > Force Symbol References and
     <at> c pjsua_lib.dll into Linker > General > Output file.
    (Otherwise some symbols would not be exported... ask me why.)
-# Build  <at> c pjsua_lib.
-# Copy  <at> c .lib and  <at> c .dll from  <at> c pjsip/bin to  <at> c 
your/location/sip/pjsua_lib.lib
    and  <at> c pjsua_lib.dll. Note that  <at> c .dll may have  <at> c .exe extension by 
mistake.
-# Copy (merge) all contents of  <at> c include directories of projects
     <at> c pjlib,  <at> c pjlib-util,  <at> c pjmedia,  <at> c pjnath,  <at> c pjsip into
     <at> c your/location/sip/include.

Process to build branch 2.x should be similar I guess, but there is no 
.dsw any more. I can provide you with a PHP script that removes mobile 
targets from .sln and .vcproj files which are then readable by Visual 
Studio, even 2010.

Good luck!
- Vali
```

**I followed all the steps. But I got 600+ errors.** I'm using latest pjsip version 2.x.

How to build pjsip as DLL in Visual studio?

Thnaks in advance!!!

Comment: https://github.com/siniypin/pjsip4net/issues/15

Comment: I think we have to build pjsua.dll as per pjsip build preparations .https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015: Right Click on project -> Build Dependencies -> Add Dependencies.
Additionally in VS 2013: Right Click on the project -> Properties -> Common Properties -> References -> Add new Reference
The list of projects need to be referenced can be copied e.g. from libproject PJSIP project.